# I am training a deepfake image detection model, but why the validation accuracy is not changing?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am training deepfake image detection using Tensorflow, but the validation accuracy is stuck at 67. I have tried to use different optimizers, but it's not decreasing and only floating around the same score.

Here is my step to creating the model.

1. Importing data from the image folder
2. Create an ImageDataGenerator object to do some augmentation.

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2,
    rescale=1./255,
)
```

3. Creating the model

image dimension: 299, 299, 3

```py
input_layer = Input(shape = (image_dimensions['height'], image_dimensions['width'], image_dimensions['channels']))

base_model = keras.applications.EfficientNetB5(
        weights='imagenet',
        input_shape=(image_dimensions['height'], image_dimensions['width'], image_dimensions['channels']),
        include_top=False)

base_model.trainable = False
x = base_model(input_layer, training=False)

# Add pooling layer or flatten layer
y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
y = Dense(512, activation='relu')(y)
y = Dropout(0.4)(y)
y = Dense(256)(y)

# Add final dense layer
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

4. Training

```
efficientNet = EfficientNet(learning_rate = 0.001)
efficientNet.summary()
history = efficientNet.fit(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, subset='training'),
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, subset='validation'))
```

5. Result

   [Here is the result of the model training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPSb.png)

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Comment: This FAQ on the stats board might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/352036/119459

Comment: I think the cause comes from the difference between generic imagenet data and specific data of Deepfake. You can split it into 2 phases. The first is that you can freeze EfficientNetB5 and fine-tune the model as you did. Second is to unfreeze EfficientNetB5 and retrain it all.

Comment: How are you compiling this model? as I don't see compilation code in the above code, which consists of optimizer and loss function to improve the model learning and accuracy.